# $this->Model->save() : what's is wrong with this code?

Tags: php, cakephp, save, cakephp-2.0

I am a beginner in cakePHP , i want to save some data into my database , but i always get : the Message : **Sorry, Error while saving data.**

Here is my code : ( Controller : `UsersController.php` : ( and i have added the Model 'UserState to the array `$uses` )

```
if($onbreak == 'true'){
    $userStatus = 1;
   //$response['userStatus'] = 1;
} else {
    $userStatus = 0;
    //$response['userStatus'] = 0;
}

//add the new user_status to the $newUserState
$newUserState['UserState']['user_id'] = $userID;// $userID = 1
$newUserState['UserState']['user_status'] = $userStatus;
//adding values for fields which should not be NULL
$newUserState['UserState']['user_phone_nb'] = '4343';

//

saving data
if($this->UserState->save($newUserState)){
    $response['success'] = 'true';
    $response['message'] = '';
}else{
    $response['success'] = 'false';
    $response['message'] = 'Sorry, Error while saving data.';
}
```

Thanks in advance

**EDIT :** 
Structure of the table userstates :

**id : BIGINT primary key AUTO INCREMENT,
   user_id : INT NOT NULL, 
   user_status : SMALLINT NOT NULL, 
   user_phone_nb = VARCHAR(15) NULL**

the Model Userstate :

```
class Userstate extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = 'userstates';
    public $name = 'UserState';
}
```

**EDIT 2 :**

when i debugg the variable $newUserState i got this ( which seems that is OK ) :

```
Array
(
    [UserState] => Array
        (
            [user_id] => 18
            [user_status] => 0
            [user_phone_nb] => 4343
        )

)
```

Comment: Do you have DEBUG set to 2 in the core.php?

Comment: see my edit  , i've added the result of my debug of the array $newUserState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution,

in my Model , i have the variable `$validate` with some parameters which have the `required` variable setted to `true`. so i've three Solutions :

**First :**

just commenting the variable and dont use it ^^

**Second:**

just initialize the required variables with a default value.

**Third :**

i found that in the doc , we can tell cakePHP to save our data without perform validation :

```
save(array
$donnees = null, boolean $valider = true, array $listeDesChamps = array())
```

so all what i did is saving data and passing the second parameter with a false value like this : `$this->UserState->save($newUserState, false);`  , ( personally i've used this Third Solution  ^^ )

Thanks you all for your help :)

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you are doing here,
could you post your table structure and the insert-query cake is generating? You find that on the bottom if you use the standard cake-layout and have debugging mode on.

I suspect (but am not sure without further data) that there is another field in the table wich needs a value (cannot be null).

Comment: thanks for your answer , i'm not using the standard cake-layout, and my table contains other fields that i want to let them blank , i want to insert just the user_status. i will verify the database if some field should not be null (+1 for this one ;) )

Comment: No problem =)
Some other suggestions:
- You can insert this command into your layout, so you see what's going on with your cake-queries:
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
- Also check if there is a field that is set to unique
- Check if there is a field with the primary key auto-incrementing

Hope i could help you.. ;-)

Comment: id : BIGINT primary key user_id : INT NOT NULL user_status : SMALLINT NOT NULL user_phone-nb = VARCHAR(15) NULL
       right away: if you save only the user_status as new record, it will surely throw an error, since user_id cannot be null, also: id (the primary key) should be set to autoincrement and a int(20) should be enough.

Comment: thanks for your reply , i have added the structure of my table ( see my edit ) , and i've tried the differents methods suggessted by other friends ,ans still getting the same msg, see my last code that i've tried.

Comment: is that have any thing with converting Strings to INT etc ??? may be something wrong with type of variables that i've tried to insert ??

Comment: wait a sec. i am trying to reproduce this error on my machine (setting up cake....  =) ).

Comment: Waaaaiiit a minute, it seems like one of those mistakes for wich you are searching hours and hours (except the fields that cannot be null, that error was true):
how did you name your model-file?
the class should be named UserState (in your example you named it Userstate), and the file user_state.php (if cake < 2.0).
I changed the name and voila it worked.   ;-)

Edit: With cake 2.0 the model-file should be UserState.php, the class still UserState. Cheers

Comment: but my table named userstates ==> so the name of the model will be like this : Userstate ( in cakePHP 2.0 ) , and if i change the name of the model to UserState, the debugger told me that the table user_states not found in the database :),

Comment: @AlexFr. is correct... the Class should be UserState the file should be user_state.php and if you add var $useTable = 'userstate'; everything should work fine.

Comment: $useTable = 'userstates'; not $useTable = 'userstate';

Comment: @lars : i've already the variable $useTable setted to userstates , and i'm working on cakePHP2.0 , so the name of my file should be Userstate.php , and my class name is Userstate because my table name is userstates ( NOT user_states) .

Comment: Hi, nope, the file should be UserState.php and the classname UserState, it has nothing to do with the table-name, since you are using $useTable (that tells cake to break its conventions and not to use the expected UserStates table).
Inside your controller you try to access the UserState Model, and if you name the model file or class differently, it surely won't find it.

Hope this helped,
Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, plz make sure about conventions in cakePHP 2.0 : if we have a table which named as : posts , so the model will be Post , and the file name will be Post.php ( post.php in cake 1.3 ) , so my table name is userstates ( NOT user_states ) , so the name of my class will be Userstate, and the file will be Userstate.php , if my table name is : user_states , so in this case , the name of my class should be UserState , and the file name will be : UserState.php . are you agree with me or not ??

Comment: to make sure, i've tried to select some fields from the table userstates using the method find , and it return the result ,so the issue is not naminge the file or the class , it may be something else ; bizarre ça :s

Comment: Hey,
it's your naming convention for sure, i've just set up cake2, and it works like a charm...
to make sure you didn't commit other mistakes, i've uploaded the controller, model and db-structure here:

http://alex-franzelin.it/downloads/app.zip

Cheers!

Ps.: I've modified it a little bit, it echos true if it works and false if not.

Comment: thanks for your help , see my answer , i've found the problem & the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the field in the DB is 'userStatus' and there is only one value to save.  But this should work and you should be able to expand on it to save other values.

Hope this helps.

Saving a new Record

```
if($onbreak == 'true'){
    $userStatus = 1;
} else {
    $userStatus = 0;
}

//add the new user_status to the $newUserState
$newUserState['UserState']['user_id'] = $userID;// $userID = 1
$newUserState['UserState']['user_status'] = $userStatus;
//adding values for fields which should not be NULL
$newUserState['UserState']['user_phone_nb'] = ' ';

// Must include id as it is a primary Key and thus required for saving.
$newUserState['UserState']['id'] = $userstate_id;


//saving data
if($this->UserState->save($newUserState)){
    $response['success'] = 'true';
    $response['message'] = '';
}else{
    $response['success'] = 'false';
    $response['message'] = 'Sorry, Error while saving data.';
}
```

Ok try this.

Rename your Model to user_state.php

Then add the following to it, based on Cake 1.2 cookbook
http://book.cakephp.org/view/436/useTable

```
<?php 
class Userstate extends AppModel {

    var $useTable = 'userstates';
    public $name = 'UserState';
}
```

Also in the config/core.php make sure the line with debug reads as follows.

```
Configure::write('debug', 2);
```

Try this and let me know your results.

Comment: i have already tried it , using an array with the same structure of the Model , but id didn't work , still getting Error While saving Data :s:s

Comment: can you please post your UserState model content... there is something that is required that is missing from the save array.

Comment: Can you also do a desc on the DB table and post it as well.. there might be something there that is required when saving... maybe a PK that is not in the Model

Comment: the PK is in the model , i will add it to my post

Comment: Try the modification that I have added $this->UserState->create()... of course this should only be used if this is a new entry.  if not you will need to the PK... most like 'id'

Comment: i've tried the method create() but still getting the same message : error while saving data, the structure of my table and my model are on my post

Comment: You must include 'id' as it is the primaryKey... You could change the id field to AutoIncrement. So when you are creating the id would not be required, but you would still need it for updating.

Comment: but my primary key is auto increment , so i dont need to add it to my $newUserState

Comment: is that have any thing with converting Strings to INT etc ??? may be something wrong with type of variables that i've tried to insert ??

Comment: its your file naming that is the issue.

Comment: if it is about file naming, it will not enter to my URL , doesn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you:

```
$this->UserState->set('UserStatus', 'New title for the article');
$this->UserState->save();
```

I hope it helps

Comment: i think that works only with the ActivRecord ( $this->UserState->read();

Answer (score 0):

Some tips at the end:

1. For cases like these it's nice to have multiple validation sets made possbile by this: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/dardosordi/2008/07/29/multivalidatablebehavior-using-many-validation-rulesets-per-model
2. Next time post complete code. The validation thing would be first guessed if you hadn't post just a 4 line represenation of your model which everyone thought was final.
3. You should reinclude the sql dump in your layout. It will not show up in live mode due of DEBUG => 0 and will help you enormous in situation like these.
4. I think the class name of the UserState model should be "UserState" and like already mentioned the file name "user_state.php". That would save a line of code :P

Greetings
func0der